# Can I change the keyboard shortcuts for tab switching in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

How do I reassign the keyboard shortcuts for Firefox? I want to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd>/<kbd>left</kbd> to switch tabs. Is there a plugin for this, if Firefox doesn’t natively support this?

Comment: I thought that this was something built in, but I've just checked and I can't find any options for it all. Is it something they've taken out of 3.6?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is what worked for me in March 2016 (Firefox 45):

1. Install the [keyconfig](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Keyconfig_extension) addon from the [keyconfig download page](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=72994) and restart.

   The addon file is unsigned, so to be able to install it, I first had to enter `about:config` in the address bar and set `xpinstall.signatures.required` to false.
2. Go to Addons -> keyconfig -> Preferences.
3. There are no "Previous Tab" and "Next Tab" entries by default, but you can add them by clicking *Add a new key* and using the following code snippets ([thanks to the author](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=323183)). The "Global" checkbox can be left unchecked.

   - *Next Tab*: `gBrowser.mTabContainer.advanceSelectedTab(1,true);`
   - *Previous Tab*: `gBrowser.mTabContainer.advanceSelectedTab(-1,true);`
4. Assign whatever keys to the "Next Tab" and "Previous Tab" actions.

(The [Customizable Shortcuts](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/customizable-shortcuts/) addon didn't work for me, as it didn't have entries for Next Tab and Previous Tab.)

Comment: This still works perfectly in Firefox 9.0.1

Comment: Lifesaver answer, works fine in Firefox 16.0.2

Comment: Still works in Firefox 31.0

Comment: Firefox 47.0 does not allow to install `keyconfig` despite `xpinstall.signatures.required=false`. Manul installtion does not also work (by both the methods).

Comment: @AlekseyF. use [this signed drop-in replacement extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dorando-keyconfig/?src=search) from addons.mozilla.org instead. The solution works perfectly with it.

Comment: I wonder if there is any addon like keyconfig that will work for Firefox 57. So far I haven't seen anything than can change shortcuts like Ctrl + Q or Ctrl + Tab

Answer (score 8):

[AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) is the answer. I tried those Firefox extensions, but they can't handle all the actions I wanted. AutoHotkey can.
Try something like this in a .ahk file:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class MozillaWindowClass
{
   ^Left::Send ^{PgUp}
   ^Right::Send ^{PgDn}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The [Keyconfig add-on](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Keyconfig_extension) for Firefox allows you to program most tab-selection keyboard binding.

Answer (score 2):

The [SwiftTabs addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/swifttabs-59011/) even lets you assign single key shortcut for tab switching

Answer (score 1):

On OS X, you can switch tabs to the left or right using option+command+left/right.  Command+{/} and ctrl+page up/down do the same thing.

I don't know if comparable shortcut keys exist on Windows, though I would guess that ctrl+page up/down work.

Source: http://support.mozilla.com/en-us/kb/keyboard+shortcuts

Comment: Thanks, although it would be better if it used ctrl+arrowkeys. Using page up/down to move across the tabbar doesn't feel natural.

Comment: Firefox also supports tab switching using CTRL+TAB & CTRL+TAB+SHIFT. Taken from http://www.techontour.com/web-browsers/2008/10/04/keyboard-shortcut-to-change-tabs-in-firefox/

Answer (score 1):

[Keybinder Addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/keybinder/) worked <strike>best</strike> first for me. More easily than the currently most popular answer.

It trivially mapped `ctrl-arrowleft` and `ctrl-arrowright` to switch between tabs left and right (on linux with firefox 45.01).

It seems good to do any keystroke I want.

I will note that, under gnome-linux, the `alt` key is bound to the desktop (for popping up the command dialog).  You can work around that by carefully hitting Shift, then Alt; rather than the Alt first.

Answer (score 0):

The [Menu Wizard](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/s3menu-wizard/) extension worked best for me. Simple and intuitive UI support. You can follow [this link](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-customize-shortcut-keys-hotkeys-in-mozilla-firefox/) for a how to.

Answer (score 0):

Since I had trouble with all the already mentioned plugins I've had to search for another way to do this. I found another Plugin that allows you to customize shortcuts that did worke: The
[dorando-keyconfig](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dorando-keyconfig/) plugin.

1. Install it from https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dorando-keyconfig/ and restart Firefox.
2. Go into **about:addons** (or open Addons Settings via the menus) and then into the Dorando Keyconfig Preferences.
3. For each of the below, press [Add a new key], add the values and check the **Global** box:

   Name:  **tab_next**
   Value: **gBrowser.mTabContainer.advanceSelectedTab(1,true);**

   Name:  **tab_prev**
   Value: **gBrowser.mTabContainer.advanceSelectedTab(-1,true);**
4. Now you can add a shortcut of your choosing to the keys.

I found those functions in the description of the plugin, which referenced the original [Mozilla Forum post](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=72994) which has a link to some [Examples](http://mozilla.dorando.at/keyconfig/examples.html).