# Switch browser tabs with Ctrl+left and Ctrl+right possible?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

I'm using Firefox for my browsing needs, and I want to make switching tabs a bit more intuitive. In my [iTerm terminal](http://iterm2.com/) I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> to switch a tab to the left or right. This works totally intuitive.

In Firefox however, I have to use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch a tab right or left respectively, which totally annoys me. Does anybody know whether and how I can customize Firefox so that I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>?

All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been answered at [superuser.com/a/333562](https://superuser.com/a/333562), I wasn't able to get AutoHotKey to use the arrows in firefox.

[EDIT]

Just to add to this I copy-pasted [the answer by Jo Liss](https://superuser.com/questions/145280/firefox-can-i-change-the-keyboard-shortcuts-for-tab-switching/333562#333562):

Here is what worked for me with Firefox 6:

1. Install the [keyconfig](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Keyconfig_extension) addon from the [keyconfig download page](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=72994) and restart.
2. Go to Addons -> keyconfig -> Preferences.
3. There are no "Previous Tab" and "Next Tab" entries by default, but you can add them by clicking *Add a new key* and using the following code snippets ([thanks to the author](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=323183)):

   - *Next Tab*: `gBrowser.mTabContainer.advanceSelectedTab(1,true);`
   - *Previous Tab*: `gBrowser.mTabContainer.advanceSelectedTab(-1,true);`
4. Assign whatever keys to the "Next Tab" and "Previous Tab" actions.

(The [Customizable Shortcuts](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/customizable-shortcuts/) addon didn't work for me, as it didn't have entries for Next Tab and Previous Tab.)